# Let $N_n$ be the number of occurrences of 5 or 6 in $n$ throws of a fair die. Show that, as $n\rightarrow\infty$,$\frac{N_n}{n}\rightarrow\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $N_n$ be the number of occurrences of 5 or 6 in $n$ throws of a fair die. Use Theorem 8.6
to show that, as $n\rightarrow \infty$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n}N_n\rightarrow \frac{1}{3} \mbox{  in mean square}
\end{equation*}

Theorem 8.6 is the Mean-square law of large numbers: Let $X_1, X_2,. . .$ be a sequence of
independent random variables, each with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. The average of the
first $n$ of the $X_i$ satisfies, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n}(X_1+...+X_n)\rightarrow \mu$ in mean square.

The textbook didn't explain this section well at all and I don't know what mean error means or how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence of $X_n$ to $X$ [in mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean) means $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left( |X_n-X|^2 \right) = 0$.  You can see the square exponent $\,^2$ and the mean $\mathbb{E}$.

As a hint to solve this, try to find the mean and variance of  $\frac{1}{n}N_n$ and then apply that to the definition of convergence in mean square.

Comment: I don't think the question wants you to use mean/variance. Rather, we need to realize $N_n$ as a sum $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ and then apply mean-square LLN.

Comment: @HaydnGwyn You may be correct, though finding the mean and variance is very quick (this case is binomial or the sum of Bernouilli) and presumably what Grimmett and Welsh used to show this theorem.